# DriveApp parent folder

Tags: google-apps-script

There is something i just don't understand about the logic in DriveApp scripting..the most basic example:

```
var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id); // makes sense, i can access the file
var name = driveFile.getName(); // makes sense, i easily get the file name

var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents(); // i get folderIterator 
var parentFolderName = // how do i get this???
```

If i look the documentation folder iterator only lets me access this:

1. getContinuationToken()  String  Gets a token that can be used to resume this iteration at a later time.
2. hasNext()   Boolean Determines whether calling next() will return an item.
3. next()  Folder  Gets the next item in the collection of files or folders.

How do i get the name for that specific parent folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because files can have more than one parent folder the parents are returned like a list or array, even if there is only one parent folder, and you have to cycle through to retrieve individual parents

```
// Log the name of every parent folder
 var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id); 
 var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
 while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
   var folder = parentFolder.next();
   Logger.log(folder.getName());
 }
```

if you were sure that the file has only one parent you could do something like:

```
var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
var folderName =parentFolder.next().getName()
```